# wordpress and dynamic page

Tags: wordpress, embed

I recently installed wordpress on localhost. I want to integrate a dynamic page to wordpress. i.e. User selects some checkboxes, I create a chart and display it.

1) Is it possible directly using wordpress?
2) Currently, the chart server is a Java server also on localhost. Can I embed the page using ?
3) I am a Java/PHP developer and I can do any modificaions required to both wordpress/chart server. I did read on the internet, but couldnt find amything.

Can you please point me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update :

I found this  -- http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/iframe/

Initial tests look promising. I will update this post if it doesnt work.

Thanks.